# ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-agents

I am trying to load a `tf-agents` policy I saved via

```
try:
    PolicySaver(collect_policy).save(model_dir + 'collect_policy')
except TypeError:
    tf.saved_model.save(collect_policy, model_dir + 'collect_policy')
```

Quick explanation for the try/except block: When originally creating the policy, I can save it via `PolicySaver`, but when I load it again for another training run, it is a `SavedModel` and can therefore not be saved by `PolicySaver`.

This seems to work fine, but now I want to use this policy for self-play, so I load the policy with `self.policy = tf.saved_model.load(policy_path)` in my AIPlayer class. When I try to use it for prediction, however, it does not work. Here's the (testing) code:

```
def decide(self, table):
    state = table.getState()
    timestep = ts.restart(np.array([table.getState()], dtype=np.float))
    prediction = self.policy.action(timestep)
    print(prediction)
```

the `table` passed into the function contains the state of the game and the `ts.restart()` function is copied from my custom pyEnvironment, so the timestep is constructed the exact same way as it would be in the environment. However, I get the following error message for the line `prediction=self.policy.action(timestep)`:

```
ValueError: Could not find matching function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(step_type=<tf.Tensor 'time_step:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, reward=<tf.Tensor 'time_step_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, discount=<tf.Tensor 'time_step_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>, observation=<tf.Tensor 'time_step_3:0' shape=(1, 79) dtype=float64>)
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}

Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(step_type=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='time_step/step_type'), reward=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_step/reward'), discount=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_step/discount'), observation=TensorSpec(shape=(None,
79), dtype=tf.float64, name='time_step/observation'))
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * TimeStep(step_type=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='step_type'), reward=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='reward'), discount=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name='discount'), observation=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 79), dtype=tf.float64, name='observation'))
    * ()
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it really just the tensor names or are the shapes the problem and how can I change that?

Any ideas how to further debug this are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it to work by constructing the TimeStep manually:

```
    step_type = tf.convert_to_tensor(
        [0], dtype=tf.int32, name='step_type')
    reward = tf.convert_to_tensor(
        [0], dtype=tf.float32, name='reward')
    discount = tf.convert_to_tensor(
        [1], dtype=tf.float32, name='discount')
    observations = tf.convert_to_tensor(
        [state], dtype=tf.float64, name='observations')
    timestep = ts.TimeStep(step_type, reward, discount, observations)
    prediction = self.policy.action(timestep)
```